# Is it possible to monitor handled exceptions using JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

This is what I have:

```
@Test
public testSendMessageToStub() {
    // under the hood sends message
    // if exception occurrs
    // it will be catched and message will be put on retry
    object.sendMessage(); 
}
```

Is there any way to mark test as failed if exception has occurred but was handled in catch block in the sendMessage() method?

Thanks

EDIT: It seems like I was too fixated on these legacy tests and how they were used, that totally missed the fact of sendMessage returning a response with a status code (!!!). So now I just assert status codes, can expand these tests into more detailed scenarios and spin them on jenkins. I would like to avoid to answer how these tests were checked previously. The thought to check for status codes came to me after reading Plux's answer. Thanks!

Comment: *and message will be put on retry* What does this mean, exactly? Is there some change in `object` when this occurs that you can observe in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what you are looking for is not possible with JUnit as far as I know.

If you really would want to test this, you could store some information about the exception in the catch-block where it is handled in the sendMessage() method.

A better option, in my opinion, could be to test the output or state of the object. If the state/output is exactly the same as when an exception doesn't occur, then whats the point of testing it? Do you have an overly broad catch-block?

EDIT: To AdityaTS, I dont have enough reputation to comment on a post, but my comment: you have not supplied all the code, so I can not say for sure, but my guess is that its the Logger.getLogger IN the catch-block that casts the ClassNotFoundException. (Either that or loadConnectionInfo()) see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this without modifying `sendMessage` method. If for example you catch the exception there but choose to ignore it and just return some value, code outside of the method doesn't know it. You can get around this by refactoring the code of `object`: move the code that handles the exception to a separate method, called e.g. `handleException`. Then, in your test you can create a subclass where `handleException` will execute the original `handleException` from superclass, but additionally set some flag which you will be able to read in your test and in this way tell that the exception was thrown. However, if you cannot modify the code for `object`'s class, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The exception generated in the `sendMessage()` class will be available in the test method. Add a try catch block around the `sendMessage()` method like this

```
@Test
public testSendMessageToStub() {

    try
       {
        object.sendMehssage(); 
       }
    catch(Excpetion e)  //Use more specific exception type if you know
       {
        fail(e.getMessage());
       }
}
```

I have tried this in my code. It worked for me. Let me know.

```
public DBConnectionInfo connectionInit()
{

    loadConnectionInfo();

    try
    {
        Class.forName(dbObject.getDriver());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(PostgreLocationManager.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    try
    {
        dbObject.setConnection(DriverManager.getConnection(dbObject.getDatabaseURL(), dbObject.getUserName(),
                dbObject.getPassword()));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(PostgreLocationManager.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return dbObject;
}
```

The test case for the above class.

```
@Test
public void testDriverFailure()
{
    when(dbModelObject.getDriver()).thenReturn("driver");
    when(dbModelObject.getDatabaseURL()).thenReturn("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb");
    when(dbModelObject.getUserName()).thenReturn("postgres");
    when(dbModelObject.getPassword()).thenReturn("postgres");

    try
    {
        dbConnector.connectionInit();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        assertTrue(e instanceof ClassNotFoundException);
    }

    verify(dbModelObject).getDriver();
}
```

Comment: It's specifically noted that the exception is caught and handled in the `sendMessage` method - it isn't re-thrown to be caught in the test.

Comment: You're missing the point. From what the OP wrote, `sendMessage` doesn't throw an exception to be caught.

Comment: It is just that I was able to test the Exception without throwing. Even I thought I wouldn't be able to do so. But it worked.

Comment: You have not supplied all the code, so I can not say for sure, but my guess is that its the Logger.getLogger IN the catch-block that casts the ClassNotFoundException. (Either that or loadConnectionInfo()) see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html

Answer (score 0):

So you expect the exception to propagate out of the `sendMessage()` method, right?

This is another way to write a test that verifies an exception you expect will be thrown.

```
@Test (expected = MyExpectedException.class)
public testSendMessageToStub() {
    // under the hood sends message
    // if exception occurrs
    // it will be catched and message will be put on retry
    object.sendMessage(); 
}
```

And it's usually best to be as specific as possible (e.g. `MyExpectedException.class` over `Exception.class`)